# Sequelize and nested results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Sequelize allows for data relationships, but I can't seem to see if there is a way to have it return a query result composed of the relation? I could do this as two queries, but I am curious as to whether Sequelize provides for this? For example Playlist and PlaylistEntry:

```
    Playlist: sequelize.define('playlist', {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
        description: Sequelize.STRING
    }),     

    PlaylistEntry: sequelize.define('playlist_entry', {
        playlist: Sequelize.INTEGER
        //track: Sequelize.INTEGER
    })

    PlaylistEntry.belongsTo(
     Playlist,
     { as: 'Playlist', foreignKey: { name: 'fk_playlist' }});
```

What I would be hoping for (pseudocode):

Query:

```
Playlist.find(where: {id: playlistId}, nestedResult: true);
```

Result:

```
[{
   id: 123,
   name: 'abc'
   playlistEntries: [{
      id: 321,
      track: 431
   }]
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Playlist.find({
  where: {}, 
  include: [
    {model: PlaylistEntry} //this should be PlaylistEntry model
  ]
})
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#eager-loading

Comment: Thanks, though I am now getting the following error: 'Error: playlist_entry is not associated to playlist!'. Not sure what I should be looking at?

Comment: Add `Playlist.hasMany(PlaylistEntry);`

Comment: AntonDrukh is right, you have to define the association in both ways. hasMany and belongsTo in the proper model